# c# mongodb driver groupby

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I try to execute this query:

```
MongoCollection<AnalyticsClicks> dbCollection = DetermineCollectionName<AnalyticsClicks>();
var query = from c in dbCollection.AsQueryable()
    where c.UserId == userId && c.CampaignId == campaignId
    select new
    {
        c.Email,
        c.Link
    };
var res = query.GroupBy(x => x.Email, b => b.Link).Count();
```

but I have exception:

> The GroupBy query operator is not supported.

I wrote a equivalent request in the robomongo

```
db.analyticsClicks.aggregate(
{ $match: { UserId: 4790, CampaignId: 92093}},
{ $group : {
        "_id" : { 
            "Email" : "$Email",
            "Link" : "$Link",
        } 
    }
})
```

It works, but I also need to get the count of items in the current collection. How can I rewrite this query using C# mongo driver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you, it is my work example

```
MongoCollection<AnalyticsClicks> dbCollection = DetermineCollectionName<AnalyticsClicks>();

            var match = new BsonDocument 
            { 
                { 
                    "$match", 
                    new BsonDocument {{"UserId", userId}, {"CampaignId", campaignId}} 
                } 
            };

            var group = new BsonDocument 
            { 
                { "$group", 
                    new BsonDocument 
                    { 
                        { "_id", new BsonDocument {{"Email", "$Email" }, {"Link", "$Link"}, }}, 
                    } 
                } 
            };

            AggregateArgs pipeline = new AggregateArgs()
            {
                Pipeline = new[] { match, group }
            };
            var result = dbCollection.Aggregate(pipeline);
            return Convert.ToInt32(result.Count());
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use aggregation framework. This example is for MongoDB.Driver 2.0

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Item>("Item");
var result = await collection
      .Aggregate()
      .Group(new BsonDocument
      {
           {
               "_id", new BsonDocument
               {
                   {"Email", "$Email"},
                   {"Link", "$Link"},
               }
           }
      })
      .Group(new BsonDocument
      {
           { "_id", "_id" },
           {"count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1)}
      })
      .FirstAsync();
var count = result["count"].AsInt32;
```

Comment: it's MongoDB.Driver 2.0

Answer (score 3):

I think the driver just doesn't implement the Linq GroupBy method. Use aggregate framework instead. You can find good examples here - [MongoDB Aggregation Framework Examples in C#](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c/)

You don't need to link any new libraries the support for the aggregation framework goes with MongoDB C# driver.

Hope it helps!